# Problema enviar objeto por socket java

Tags: java, arraylist

estoy intentando enviar un objeto por Sockets y no logro entender como hacerlo, se como hacerlo de una manera pero no me viene bien.

Quiero enviar un Objeto Carrito que a su vez tiene un atributo que es ArrayList de tipo Alimento. Os dejo las clases, son cortas.

```
public class Carrito implements Serializable {
public static ArrayList<Alimento> carrito_alimentos = new ArrayList<>();

public static void addAlimento(Alimento alimento){
    carrito_alimentos .add(alimento);
}

public static void removeAlimento(Alimento alimento){
    carrito_alimentos .remove(alimento);
}

public ArrayList<Alimento> getCarrito() {
    return carrito_alimentos ;
}
}

public class Alimento implements Serializable{
private String id,nombre,precio,fotoAlimento;

public Alimento(String id, String nombre, String precio, String fotoAlimento) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.fotoAlimento = fotoAlimento;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public String getFotoAlimento() {
    return fotoAlimento;
}
```

Hasta ahí todo OK, cuando envio el objeto Carrito por Socket, el arraylist qeuda VACÍO en el dispositivo al que se lo he enviado, sin embargo, he mirado en consola y se guardan bien los alimentos antes de enviar el carrito.

Pero si le paso en vez de un objeto de tipo Carrito al socket, le paso un List, funciona perfectamente, y esta opción no me vale.

Os dejo el socket cliente, (el writeobject carrito repito que no tiene valores nulos ni vacios, se le asignan en otra parte del código, aqui pongo lo mas importante)

Cliente:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);

    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

    
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(carrito);

    System.out.println("Closing socket and terminating program.");
    socket.close();
```

Servidor:

```
try {
        ssocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
        while (true) {              
            s=ssocket.accept();
             
            InputStream inputStream = s.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
            Carrito carrito = (Carrito) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(carrito); //devuelve el hashchode del objeto
            
            System.out.println(cuentaRecibido.getCarrito()); //devuelve null
            System.out.println(cuentaRecibido.size()); //devuelve 0
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;TR**: Los atributos estáticos de una clase **NO** son serializables

En tu código estás serializando y deserializando un objeto que tiene atributos estáticos, además el método `getCarrito()` que no es estático, está retornando un atributo estático, pero nuevamente, los atributos estáticos no son serializables.

De la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The readObject method is responsible for reading from the stream and restoring the classes fields. It may call in.defaultReadObject to invoke the default mechanism for restoring the object's **non-static and non-transient** fields

Para solucionarlo solo hay que cambiar el diseño de tus clases a uno correcto, que tenga atributos de instancia, no atributos de clase (no `static`).

Revisa también [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008023/how-to-serialize-static-data-members-of-a-java-class).